# Using Scipy ode solver to solve stiff coupled odes

Tags: python, scipy, ode

At the moment, I am trying to solve a system of coupled ODEs. I am using scipy.integrate.ODE. The system has 4 coupled ODEs, which relates outdoor temperature to indoor temperature. The goal is to integrate the ode to get the indoor temperature and match it against the actual indoor temperature. The 't_out' function in one of the ode return a outdoor temperature at a specific time. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

time_step = 60

ending = 1300

n=0

df = pd.read_csv("Temperature.csv").loc[0:ending+51,]
df['Tsol (HKO)'] = df['Tsol (HKO)']+273
df['Temp_In'] = df['Temp_In']+273
t_out_list = df['Tsol (HKO)'].tolist() #Assign outdoor temperature
t_in_list = df['Temp_In'].tolist() #Assign actual indoor temperature


def initial_temp():
    t_in, t_out = t_in_list, t_out_list
    t1 = t_in[0] - (t_in[0] - t_out[0])/3
    t2 = t_in[0] - (t_in[0] - t_out[0])*2/3
    t_im = t_in = t_in[0]
#    return [t_in[0], t_in[0], t_in[0], t_in[0]]
    return[t_in, t1, t2, t_im]



def t_out(t):
    index = int(t/time_step)
    upper_t, lower_t = t_out_list[index+1], t_out_list[index]
    return (upper_t-lower_t)*(t/60.0-index) + lower_t



def fun(t, u, R1, R2, R3, R_IM, C1, C2, C_IN, C_IM):

    global sol, ttt
    sol.append(u[0])
    ttt.append(t/time_step)

    T_in, T1, T2, T_im = u[0], u[1], u[2], u[3]
    dT_in = ((T2 - T_in)/R3 + (T_im - T_in)/R_IM)/C_IN
    dT1 = ((t_out(t) - T1)/R1 - (T1 - T2)/R2)/C1
    dT2 = ((T1 - T2)/R2 - (T2 - T_in)/R3)/C2
    dT_im = ((T_im - T_in)/R_IM)/C_IM

#    print(dT_in, dT1, dT2, dT_im)
    return [dT_in, dT1, dT2, dT_im]


def jacobian_fun(t, u, R1, R2, R3, R_IM, C1, C2, C_IN, C_IM):

    return [ [ -1/(R3*C_IN) , 0 , 1/(R3*C_IN) , 1/(R_IM*C_IN) ] , 
             [ 0 , -1/(R1*C1)-1/(R2*C1) , 1/(R2*C1) , 0 ] , 
             [ 1/(R3*C2) , 1/(R2*C2) ,-1/(R2*C2)-1/(R3*C2), 0 ] ,
             [ -1/(R_IM*C_IM), 0 , 0 , 1/(R_IM*C_IM) ] ]


def thermal_ode_error(g):

    R1, R2, R3, R_IM, C1, C2, C_IN, C_IM = g
    A = u0 = initial_temp()
    r = ode(fun, jacobian_fun).set_integrator('vode', nsteps=500, method='bdf', with_jacobian = True)
    r.set_initial_value(u0, 0.0).set_f_params(R1, R2, R3, R_IM, C1, C2, C_IN, C_IM).set_jac_params(R1, R2, R3, R_IM, C1, C2, C_IN, C_IM)

    j = ending*time_step

    while r.successful() and r.t < j:
        r.integrate(r.t+time_step)
        A = np.vstack([A, r.y])
    return A[:,0]


sol = []
ttt = []


g = [0.03, 0.05, 0.16, 0.02, 444046, 111695, 529127.0, 42000.0]
T_in_calculated = thermal_ode_error(g)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 4)

del ttt[1], sol[1]

plt.plot([x for x in range(0,len(t_in_list))], t_in_list)
plt.plot([x for x in range(0,len(t_out_list))], t_out_list, color='g')
plt.plot(ttt, sol, color='r')
plt.plot([x for x in range(0,len(T_in_calculated))], T_in_calculated, '*--')

x1,x2,y1,y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((0,300,295, 302))
```

Here is the link to Temperature.csv data,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84_Z1V4nj9ScG5sa1BSM1lneVk/view?usp=sharing

The data contains sample reading with 60 second interval, and t_out function in the ode output a reading from the data with each time step. (Hope this makes sense.)

and here is the result I get.
[image]

The green line is the outdoor temperature, red line is the calculated indoor temperature, and as you can see it doesn't come anywhere near the actual indoor temperature (blue line). Now it could be the parameters of the ode e.g. R1, R2... are slightly off, but it shouldn't affect the result too much, I think it is problem with the way I solve the ode.

I have been stuck on this issue for a few days so any help I can get is welcome!

Comment: Did you check your equations? Always do that first. The jacobian is wrong, equation for T_im is probably wrong (difficult to say since the model is not specified).

Comment: In addition to what @pv. said, try to solve it [semi-exactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Systems_of_linear_differential_equations). It'll probably be slower, but you'll have an independent check.